# Shared hosting behind Cloudflare

Tags: 7, configuration

I use Drupal 7 at a share hosting account (with apache server) and I use Cloudflare.com CDN.
Cloudflare ip token (at webform etc) shows cloudflare IP instead of visitor's original IP.

At settings.php I put

```
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$conf['reverse_proxy_header'] = 'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP';
```

These did not seem to work.

What seems to work was:
the instructions given by cloudflare for PHP

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]) {$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]; }
```

or alternatively what was written at drupal cloudflare module (which is only for drupal 6 and not 7)

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] ? $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] : $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

The questions are

- why the typical drupal settings ($conf['reverse_proxy_header) did not work, and how can I make them work?
- If not, then which of the 2 solutions that worked for me is more secure or better?
- Should I setup $conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] with cloudflare ips,
  or it's useless since $conf['reverse_proxy_header'] does not work
  anyway?

Comment: I checked it out with one of our API guys & option 2 looks to be the way to go. Is your host not willing to install [mod_cloudflare](http://www.cloudflare.com/wiki/Log_Files)? This is perhaps the easiest way to do this.

Comment: The question is for hosts that are not using mod_cloudflare. I am expecting someone to answer if there is a way to use the normal drupal $conf at settings.php, without resorting in extra php code, not documented by drupal. How drupal is supposed to work with those $conf value? Am I doing something wrong, or there is a bug in drupal?

Comment: which of the 2 solutions that worked for me is more secure or better?
Should I setup $conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] with cloudflare ips, or it's useless since $conf['reverse_proxy_header'] does not work anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you install the [CloudFlare - Free Reverse Proxy, Firewall, and Global CDN](http://drupal.org/project/cloudflare) module? The module comes with instructions on how to solve this problem:

**Installation Instructions:**

> Install and Enable this module. Add one line of code at the end of
>   your settings.php file:
>
> ```
> $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] ? $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] : $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
> ```
>
> Save your email address and CloudFlare API key to the CloudFlare administration screen on your Drupal web site (admin/settings/cloudflare).